How can I hide the bottom tab bar on a specific screen in React Native using React Navigation?
I'm developing a React Native app using React Navigation for navigation. I have a bottom tab navigator set up to navigate between different screens in my app. However, I encountered an issue where I don't want the bottom tab bar to be displayed on the "Product Detail" screen.
Here's a simplified version of my navigation setup:
// Imports
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import {
  AntDesign,
  Entypo,
  EvilIcons,
  Feather,
  FontAwesome5,
  MaterialCommunityIcons,
  Octicons,
} from "@expo/vector-icons";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

// Context
import { useLocation } from "../context/LocationContext";

// Components
import Header from "../components/Header";

// Screens
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import AllowLocation from "../screens/AllowLocation";
import SelectSignUpMethod from "../screens/OnBoarding/SelectSignUpMethod";
import Profile from "../screens/Tabs/Profile";
import Search from "../screens/Tabs/Search";
import Cart from "../screens/Tabs/Cart";
import CustomeDrawer from "../components/Drawer/CustomeDrawer";
import SignUpScreen from "../screens/OnBoarding/SignUpScreen";
import LogInScreen from "../screens/OnBoarding/LogInScreen";
import VerifyEmailScreen from "../screens/OnBoarding/VerifyEmailScreen";
import AddPhoneNumberScreen from "../screens/OnBoarding/AddPhoneNumberScreen";
import VerifyPhoneScreen from "../screens/OnBoarding/VerifyPhoneScreen";
import PinLocationScreen from "../screens/PinLocationScreen";
import SplashScreen from "../screens/SplashScreen";
import ChatScreens from "../screens/chat/ChatScreens";
import Help from "../screens/HelpCenter/Help";
import HelpDetails from "../screens/HelpCenter/HelpDetails";
import RestaurantScreen from "../screens/RestaurantScreen/RestaurantScreen";
import ProductDetail from "../screens/ProductDetails/ProductDetail";

// Context
import { useUser } from "../context/UserInfoContext";
import ChatHeader from "../screens/chat/chatHeader";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const HomeStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Main Home"
      component={Home}
      options={{ header: () => <Header /> }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="RestaurantScreen"
      component={RestaurantScreen}
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="ProductDetail"
      component={ProductDetail}
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const ProfileStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Main Profile"
      component={Profile}
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const CartStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Cart">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Cart"
        component={Cart}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
const SearchStack = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Search"
      component={Search}
      options={{ headerShown: true }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>;
};

const TabNavigator = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarStyle: {
        height: 57,
        backgroundColor: "#46B5A2",
        paddingTop: 10,
        
      },
      tabBarActiveTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#2A7D6E",
      tabBarLabel: "",
      header: () => <Header />,
    }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name={"Home"}
      component={HomeStack}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <Octicons name="home" size={size} color={color} />
        ),
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name={"Cart"}
      component={CartStack}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <Feather name="shopping-bag" size={size} color={color} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name={"Search"}
      component={SearchStack}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <Feather name="search" size={size} color={color} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name={"Profile"}
      component={ProfileStack}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <AntDesign name="user" size={size} color={color} />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

const HelpStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Help"
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: true,
      header: () => <ChatHeader />,
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen name="Help" component={Help} />
    <Stack.Screen name="HelpDetails" component={HelpDetails} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

// App Drawer Navigator
const AppDrawer = () => (
  <Drawer.Navigator
    drawerContent={(props) => <CustomeDrawer {...props} />}
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      drawerStyle: {
        width: 330,
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 30,
      },
      drawerLabelStyle: {
        marginLeft: -20,
        fontFamily: "Gotham-Medium",
        fontSize: 13,
      },
      drawerItemStyle: {
        paddingVertical: 5,
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
        borderBottomColor: "#EFEFEF",
        paddingLeft: 5,
        borderRadius: 5,
      },
      drawerActiveBackgroundColor: "#46B5A2",
      drawerActiveTintColor: "#fff",
      // overlayColor: 'transparent',
    }}
  >
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="View Profile"
      component={TabNavigator}
      options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
          <FontAwesome5 name="user-circle" size={28} color={color} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="Inbox"
      component={TabNavigator}
      options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
          <Feather name="inbox" size={28} color={color} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="Addresses"
      component={TabNavigator}
      options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
          <Entypo name="address" size={28} color={color} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="OrderReOrdering"
      component={TabNavigator}
      options={{
        title: "Orders & Re-Ordering",
        drawerIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="text-box-check-outline"
            size={28}
            color={color}
          />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="Help Center"
      component={HelpStack}
      options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
          <Feather name="life-buoy" size={28} color={color} />
        ),
        headerShown: false,
        // header: () => <ChatHeader />,
      }}
    />

    <Drawer.Screen
      name="Setting"
      component={TabNavigator}
      options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
          <AntDesign name="setting" size={28} color={color} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="ChatScreens"
      component={ChatScreens}
      options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
          <AntDesign name="setting" size={28} color={color} />
        ),
        headerShown: true,
        header: () => <ChatHeader />,
      }}
    />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
);

const OnBoardingStack = () => {
  const { user, setUserInfo, updateUserInfo, clearUserInfo } = useUser();

  let innitialRouteName = "SelectSignUpMethod";

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={innitialRouteName} //Should change to "SelectSignUpMethod"
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, animation: "slide_from_bottom" }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name={"SignUp"} component={SignUpScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={"SelectSignUpMethod"}
        component={SelectSignUpMethod}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name={"LogIn"} component={LogInScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={"VerifyEmail"} component={VerifyEmailScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={"PhoneNumberScreen"}
        component={AddPhoneNumberScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name={"VerifyPhone"} component={VerifyPhoneScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const LocationStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"AllowLocation"}>
    <Stack.Screen
      name={"AllowLocation"}
      component={AllowLocation}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name={"PinLocationScreen"}
      component={PinLocationScreen}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const AppNavigation = () => {
  const { location, setLocation } = useLocation();
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);

  const locationPermission = location.latitude !== null;

  return (
    <>
      {locationPermission === true ? (
        <>
          {isLogin ? (
            <>
              <AppDrawer />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <OnBoardingStack />
            </>
          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <LocationStack />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default AppNavigation;

How can I hide the bottom tab bar on the "Product Detail" screen while keeping it visible on other screens in my app? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

For Hiding the bottom bar on Specific tab, you can do this
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Product_Detail"
    component={Product Detail}
    options={{ tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' } }}
  />

